# Does ML.NET CategoricalOneHotVectorizer encode testing data as well?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I'm not sure how ML.NET CategoricalOneHotVectorizer works, from their sample code,

```
var pipeline = new LearningPipeline
{
    // ... extra code ...
    new CategoricalOneHotVectorizer("VendorId", "RateCode", "PaymentType"),
    // ... extra code ...
    new FastTreeRegressor()
};
```

looks to me that once we call model = pipeline.Train() to train the model, it do coding on the categorical input data only. So if my test data has some values that are not in the input, would it mess up the prediction result?

Normally on Python I would train the OneHotEncoder on both training and testing data before using it to encode categorical variables. Not sure how to do that with ML.NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use your testing data to train your model. That is a mistake. All one hot encoding machine learning frameworks will encode an unseen category as all nulls by default.
ML.NET v0.7 will do the same:

```
public static void TryOneHot()
{
  var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 4).Select(i => new { A = $"{i}", B = $"{i}" });
  var trainData = data.Take(3).ToArray();
  var testData = data.Skip(3).ToArray();
  using (var env = new ConsoleEnvironment(seed: 1, conc: 1))
  {
    var dataView = env.CreateDataView(trainData).AssertStatic(env, c => (A: c.Text.Scalar, B: c.Text.Scalar));
    var encoderPipe = dataView.MakeNewEstimator()
      .Append(row => (
        A_OH: row.A.OneHotEncoding(),
        B_OH: row.B.OneHotEncoding()
      ));
    var encoder = encoderPipe.Fit(dataView);

    var encodedTrainingData = encoder.AsDynamic.Transform(env.CreateDataView(trainData));
    var raw = encodedTrainingData.GetColumn<float[]>(env, "A_OH").ToArray();

    var encodedTestData = encoder.AsDynamic.Transform(env.CreateDataView(testData));
    var rawUnseen = encodedTestData.GetColumn<float[]>(env, "A_OH").ToArray();
  }
}
```

If you inspect `rawUnseen` you'll see that it will be `[0, 0, 0]` encoded, since the category has never been seen.

Comment: In ML.NET, how would we address the issue where the test or actual categorical value being seen as null if it does not appear during the training?